# Decentralized algorithm for a one dimensional ring structured graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm working on a homework in which a graph of n nodes is arranged as a one-dimensional ring and every node has 3 out-going edges.

I need some help in proving that any decentralized algorithm would need at least Ω(√n) steps to forward the message from a node A to B if the nodes A and B are √n distance apart on the ring.

Comment: I can't visualise a ring in which every node has 3 out-edges -- can you explain further?

Comment: one out edge to the node on the left, one out edge to the node on the right and one out edge to a randomly selected node in the graph.